# Why it doesn't work? Simple multithreading example

Tags: c++, multithreading

can you help me with understanding why does this code freeze the program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

int i = 0;

mutex mx;

void foo() {
    while(1) {
        lock_guard<mutex> locker(mx);
        i++;
        if(i == 5000) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void boo() {
    while(1) {
        if(i == 100) {
            lock_guard<mutex> locker(mx);
            i = 5000;
            break;
         }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    thread th1(foo);
    thread th2(boo);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Why do I have such a result?
How to change the code to make it right? Could you give me your thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "right"?

Comment: You would have to be *very* lucky to observe i==100.  Most typically the thread starts running and zooms past i > 100 in a few microseconds before the second thread starts.  So th2.join() hangs forever.

Comment: Computers are *fast*. There's nothing to stop `foo` running multiple iterations of its loop before `boo` starts running. It could then be that `i` is much larger than `100` when `boo` checks the value for the first time, meaning it will never end.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even if `boo()` starts in time there is no guarantee that `foo()` cannot make multiple increments btw `boo()` checks, despite the fact there is race condition in checking `i`

Comment: Other comments (which should be _answers,_ B.T.W.) probably are correct, but as a side note, your `boo` thread tests `i` without locking the mutex (`if (i == 100) {...}`). That's bad. Locking a mutex does more than just prevent other threads from locking the same mutex at the same time. It also impacts the _visibility_ of updates to shared variables. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so already, get yourself one or more books on how to properly write multithread programs in C++.  Multithread programming isn't a topic you can just figure out by trial and error -- it is a very complex, and the best way to get involved in it is to work from working samples of code.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that technically creates a data race.. which then technically creates undefined behavior. That said as the answers point out... the code has serious issues in regards to assumptions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Even if `boo` starts running first, it will probably never see `i==100`.

If you only have one CPU, then it's very unlikely that the CPU would be switched from `foo` to `boo` while `i==100`.

If you have multiple CPUs, then `i==100` will probably never even make it into `foo's` cache, because `i` is not volatile, and the mutex is not locked between reads.

Really the compiler doesn't even have to read `i` after the first time, because there are no memory barriers.  It can assume that the value hasn't changed.

Even if you were to fix this, the distinct possibility would remain that `i` could be incremented past 100 before `boo` would notice.  It looks like you expect the two threads to "take turns", but that's just not how it works.

Comment: Would moving `lock_guard<mutex> locker(mx);` before the `if(i == 100) {` gurantee that the `i` has to be reread?

Comment: @t.niese technically yes, however it doesn't change the fact that `i == 100` relies on an unsafe assumption that the reader will *see* `i` when it reaches that point. Of which there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Mgetz yes that's clear to me. I was just wondering if locking the mutex is sufficient, that the compiler won't assume that `i` does not change anymore after the first check.

Comment: @t.niese well the compiler is not free to move the read above the mutex. So in theory it should "Work." The fact that `i` is static and referenced in two places means the compiler can't optimize the entire thing out as it normally would. The standard requires a program to be "Sequentially consistent, Data race free" to not have undefined behavior.

Comment: @t.niese But why second thread doesn't end if I change if(i == 100) to if(i > 100)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concurrency issues with your solution:

1. You have to lock the mutex consistently. *All* access to `i` must be protected by the mutex, so also at the `if (i == 100) {` line. In the absence of synchronization, the compiler is free to optimize the thread as-if it was running in isolation, and assume `i` to never change.
2. There is no guarantee that `boo` will start before `foo`. If it starts after, `i` will already be incremented well above `100`.
3. Mutex locking is not guaranteed to be fair. Two threads competing for the same mutex will not run in an interleaved manner. Which means `foo` might increment `i` many times before `boo` gets a chance to run, so the value of `i` as seen by `boo` might easily jump from `0` to `1000`, skipping the desired `100`.
4. In isolation, `foo` will "run away", incrementing `i` well beyond `5000`. There should be some exit or a restart condition.

> *How to change the code to make it right?*

Add some synchronization in order to enforce interleaved processing. For example, using `condition_variable`s to signal between threads:

```
int i = 0;

mutex mx;
condition_variable updated_cond;
bool updated = false;
condition_variable consumed_cond;
bool consumed = true;

void foo() {
    while (1) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mx);
        consumed_cond.wait(locker, [] { return consumed; });
        consumed = false;
        if (i == 5000) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "foo: i = " << i << "+1\n";
        i++;
        updated = true;
        updated_cond.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << "foo exiting\n";
}

void boo() {
    for (bool exit = false; !exit; ) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mx);
        updated_cond.wait(locker, [] { return updated; });
        updated = false;
        std::cout << "boo: i = " << i << "\n";
        if (i == 100) {
            i = 5000;
            exit = true;
        }
        consumed = true;
        consumed_cond.notify_one();
    }
    std::cout << "boo exiting\n";
}
```

Comment: @t.niese yes, of course, I missed the insufficient locking in the question, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the program is undefined, so reasoning about what it does is futile. The problem is that `boo` reads the value of `i` and `foo` both reads and writes the value of `i`, but the read of `i` in `if (i == 100)` in `boo` is unsequenced with respect to the writes occurring in `foo`. That's a data race, and the behavior of the program is undefined. Sure, you can guess at what might happen, but if you want your code to run correctly, you have to ensure that there are no data races. That means using some form of synchronization: either move the lock in `boo` **before** the `if`, or get rid of the mutex and change the type of `i` to `std::atomic<int>`.